# automatic vs on-the-heap objects, std, dll

Tags: c++, dll, std

Using MS VS 2012, I create std::vector, then pass it to a function to be filled:

```
void foo() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    bar(vec);
}
void bar(std::vector<std::string> &v) {
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)`
        v.push_back(std::string("str"));
}
```

If both functions are defined as above, no error. If bar is located in a DLL, there is 'BAD_BLOCK' failure when exiting foo.
However, if I change to:

```
void foo() {
    std::vector<std::string> *vec = new std::vector<std::string>();
    bar(vec);
}
void bar(std::vector<std::string> *v) {
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)`
        v->push_back(std::string("str"));
}
```

there is no error when using DLL. Any idea why it behaves differently in these two cases?

Comment: Is the dll compiled with the same compiler version, same configuration and same CRT settings as your application?

Comment: Same, but as it turns out, one was wrong - see below, I was using statically-linked CRT in both DLL and calling EXE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the DLL version of the CRT? If you use the statically linked version in one or both it will fail, because one copy of the CRT allocates the memory used by the vector and strings and the other attempts to free it.

You must use the DLL version of the CRT throughout.

(In your second version you sidestep the issue by leaking the memory instead.)

Comment: Thank you! This was indeed the case. Too bad I don't have enough reputations to vote you up yet :(